# Create a new folder in s3 bucket with powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

Is it possible to create a new folder, whose name is the current date, in an S3 bucket?

I am writing a script which, each time it executes, sends a file to an S3 bucket. I need it to make a new folder whose name is today's date.

**Edit**

I am using

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName $bucketName -File "$Directory\$file"
```

$file comes from a foreach cycle, it is a file within a local folder.
$Directory is the path where the files are located

Comment: You can simply upload `cat.png` to `s3://mybucket/YYYYMMDD/cat.png` without having to pre-create `YYYYMMDD/` in the bucket.

Comment: Add `-Key "2021-12-02/$file"` when calling Write-S3Object to set the desired S3 object key. Feel free to get the date dynamically from PowerShell, using `Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"`.

Comment: @jarmod Awesomw that's exactly what I needed. Write this as an answer and I'll check your answer and the solution. Thank you man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to be aware of is that you can simply upload a file named, for example, `cat.png` to `s3://mybucket/YYYY-MM-DD/cat.png` without having to pre-create `YYYY-MM-DD/` in the bucket.

Your current script is:

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName $bucketName -File "$Directory\$file"
```

This doesn't explicitly set the key of the target S3 object, so it's implied from the filename.

To indicate a specific key including a date prefix, add the following when calling Write-S3Object:

```
-Key "2021-12-02/$file"
```

Of course, you might prefer to get today's date dynamically from PowerShell rather than hard-code 2012-12-02, and you can do that using:

```
Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually create folders in S3, though they may be shown like that when you use the web console and other viewers to make it easier to be readable by humans.

What you can do is add the date as the *prefix* to your file name when uploading it, so the destination file's name (or rather, the object's key) would be something like 'date/sourcename'.

Comment: Didn't get this "What you can do is add the date as the prefix to your file name when uploading it"

Comment: You format the date into whatever string you like and prepend it to the destination "filename". Like running the command 'aws s3 cp myfile s3://mybucket/2021-12-02/myfile'

Comment: Oh ok, but I am not using aws s3 cp, I am using powershell aws commands, in this case Write-Object. I have edited my question, to explain that

Comment: I meant it as an example. You prepend the date to the destination file's name.